# Migration of Drupal 6 to Drupal 7

Tags: 7, nodes, migrations

I have a Drupal 6 site with different content types, and node references. I also have a custom theme. I want to migrate to Drupal 7. 
I use the Node export, and Node import modules, but they are not working perfectly, as I am not able to import node references.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: look for the upgrade process [here](http://drupal.org/documentation/upgrade/6/7)...

Answer (score 1):

1. Read the [UPGRADE.txt](http://drupal.org/node/550126)
2. Have a look at the [CCK Module for D7](http://drupal.org/project/cck). It comes with a migration submodule.
3. The them has to be adapted to D7 manually. Have a look at [this for reference](http://drupal.org/node/254940).

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below points to migrate drupal 6 to drupal 7,

- Take up a backup of your Drupal website and the database set on it.
- Put your production website into Maintenance mode to make sure no new data is being recorded on it.
- Configure the backup of Drupal to a test environment, such as a subfolder or subdomain.
- Perform the upgrade to D7 on the test website.
- Test if all features on your upgraded, test website are working properly.
- If you are happy with the result, switch places of your test and production website, so the upgraded version will become the main one on your server.

From the points, if you need any queries let me know.